# react-router server side redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, reactjs, react-router

How to do redirect on server side, while componentWillMount?

1. User types /event/123/something-here
2. If needs redirect, need to redirect him to /event/123/-true-url

```js
   static contextTypes = {
      router: React.PropTypes.any
    };

    static needs = [
        EventActions.getEvent
    ];

    componentWillMount() {
      if(this.props.event.get('redirect')) {
        let path = this.props.event.get('redirect');
        this.context.router.push(this.props.event.get('redirect'));
        //console.log(this.context);
      }
    }
```

Nothing happens. No warnings. Url is relative.
Child component starts rendering. This component is container.

Comment: Can you do the redirect on the express.js level (or whatever framework you are using to serve the page)? I am not sure if componentWillMount will get called on the server side (haven't tested it)

Comment: componentWillMount working nice.